# Why gradient-like dynamical systems are special case of Morse-Smale systems?

Tags: differential-topology, dynamical-systems, morse-theory

I'm studying Morse Theory and my question is exactly as stated in the above title.
I can't see how a [gradient-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient-like_vector_field) dynamical system could be considered as a [Morse-Smale system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Smale_system)?

Thanks in advance for any illuminating contribution.
Any relevant references are also much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly puzzles you? It is very easy to see that all the rest points are hyperbolic and corrsepond to the critical points of the Morse function. It is also easy to see that every orbit is either trapped to a local minimum or (in rare cases) can land on a saddle point. Picture in wikipedia gives idea why invariant manifolds are transverse.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got the point. It was just a matter of more thinking!